# what does StructLayout.Auto mean compared to sequential and Explicit?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I think LayoutKind.Sequential and LayoutKind.Explicit are clear, but how is LayoutKind.Auto handled by C#?

Comment: What in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) did you not understand?

Comment: @Oded The documentation doesn't specify the inner workings of how `Auto` works, which I think is what the OP is driving at. I don't think this questoin deserves the downvotes it's getting.

Comment: @JohnFeminella - The question is getting downvoted because it is not clear. The OP didn't specify what he does not understand - your guess is as good as any.

Answer (score 4):

`LayoutKind.Auto` just means, "I give the CLR permission to reorder the bytes corresponding to these fields". It decides exactly how to reorganize the fields for memory usage, packing, et cetera. **Exactly which changes** it will make isn't specified by the documentation, probably because it's an implementation detail that isn't relevant to how you write your structs.

This is invariably a bad thing if you're passing to unmanaged code, because unmanaged code expects those fields to be in a particular order. Their possible rearrangement is bound to have unintended consequences. That's why you can't expose `LayoutKind.Auto` structs to unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) seems pretty clear:

> The runtime automatically chooses an appropriate layout for the
>   members of an object in unmanaged memory. Objects defined with this
>   enumeration member cannot be exposed outside of managed code.
>   Attempting to do so generates an exception.

In other words, the layout is dynamic and means that your object can no longer be used outside of Managed Code.

Answer (score 1):

MS says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx)

> The common language runtime uses the Auto layout value by default. To
>   reduce layout-related problems associated with the Auto value, C#,
>   Visual Basic, and C++ compilers specify Sequential layout for value
>   types.

Answer (score 0):

[The runtime automatically chooses an appropriate layout for the members of an object in unmanaged memory.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx)